# Protection of new users from aggression

Tags: discussion, new-users, behavior

I have been on this site for a couple of days and brought with me a personal puzzle [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074409/return-elements-from-both-sides-of-item-in-array). I had people who totally understood this question and provided some answers.

On the other hand, specific two people have made comments about the clarity of the question, but they were not able to ***emphatically*** say why or what was unclear.

As a new user, I think this was quite aggressive and unpleasant.

I was willing to provide all information needed to clarify.

In short, I think it's not enough for anyone of higher points to just say a question is not clear. I'm sure anyone can do this. The true distinction is the ability to nonaggressively and clearly point out what exactly is wrong. If not, how do we tell a person claiming a question is not clear is doing so out of personal reasons rather than constructive criticisms?

Comment: Re *"how do we tell a person claiming a question is not clear is doing so out of personal reasons"*: You can not know another person's motives. Nothing good comes out of speculating about it. Instead, assume good intent.

Comment: I agree and of course the personal reason is most probably of good intent. My exact concern is, how healthy is this behavior towards the new joiner? How helpful is this behavior to the general community ?  Also by leaving it all to assumptions, are we also not opening the door for this to be possibly abused ? If we have community moderation with the ability to address this, then why not ?

Comment: FYI, synthetic puzzles will not generally be well received. The site is meant as a Q&A for practical programming issues. While there can be some overlap between a "puzzle" and a "practical issue", we prefer questions being based on real problems or situations, for which the answer can help future users. Solving puzzles help only the person solving the puzzle, but it's not generally a useful thing to read for future users.

Comment: thanks @yivi for this clarity. I have two questions pls; 1. If puzzles are not meant to be well received, can we make that clear in policy ? So that users do not mistakenly post puzzles. 2. If I had posted this question as a real problem without disclosing that I synthesized it, would it have been known ? Also, would it have been well received ? And would you have considered this helpful not just for me but the whole community ?

Comment: It's unlikely the question would have been posed like this if it was a real problem. You'll find that when you are working on a real situation, the whole problem statement and research change completely. In the unlikely case one still posted **this** as a "real problem needing a solution", it would still be a very poorly researched question (which could have lead to downvotes), but that's a different thing.

Comment: Agree on the dynamics of a real problem question. But is it possible for a down-vote to be more than merely a click ?  Such that if one thinks a question is poorly researched, they are tasked with providing clarity of why they think so ?  If one just cast a down-vote with no explanation, how does it help the post owner realize how or where they were wrong ?

Comment: @user23463397 as a general guidance if you're asking about such puzzle / toy problems it is best to ask about the exact problem you are stuck on rather than a solution for the entire problem. For example: How do I get N elements before index i? How do I get all indices in an array which have a specific value? Note that these might be duplicates so search first before asking!

Comment: You are now branching into a different topic: downvotes do not require comments, that's something that has been discussed to the boringly long extents and the result is always the same. Users use their votes to cast their opinion about posts. If one receives one or more downvotes, one should assume someone found the post either unclear, poorly researched, or simply not useful. One should take that into consideration and try to improve the post if possible.

Comment: @user23463397 see: [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr)

Comment: I think we may need to reconsider our definition of problem such that it is generalized to include synthetic ones. Or maybe a new stack for synthetic problems ? Because in the tech field, especially for programming, we learn a lot from synthetic problems. I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @user23463397 The site is meant for users who look for **solutions**. I have a **problem**, I search for a **solution**, which exists because someone else had a similar problem in the past, and got an answer with a similarly applicable solution. Puzzles, do not generally help grow a corpus of **solutions** to **practical problems**. I do not intend to discuss this anymore, I was just giving you feedback and advice so you were more successful in your future SO interactions. Use it, or not. It's up to you.

Comment: I look at that post you link and it doesn't *read* like a question. It reads like a homework assignment; one you've set the users of [so] to complete. In the entirety of the post (Question) you don't actually ask *any* questions. You don't explain the difficulty *you* are having solving the puzzle you've created, or what about your attempts aren't working (and what they are). It might seem like a silly thing to state, but part of posting a question means *asking a question*.

Comment: "Synthetic programming puzzle to solve with the community." - **We don't do that here**. "If puzzles are not meant to be well received, can we make that clear in policy ?" It is already abundantly clear [in policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - questions need to be **practical**. You could also try looking at existing, recent, well-received questions to get some idea about what is considered appropriate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have read the policy you referenced; "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it. The best Stack Overflow questions generally have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
    a specific programming problem, or
    a software algorithm, or
    software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
    a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
…then you’re in the right place to ask your question! " .

Comment: Ref: policy ".... anyone who writes code because they love it..." that sounds like synthetic programming questions are not forbidden

Comment: A *puzzle* isn't a question, @user23463397 .

Comment: @ThomA would you consider a puzzle to be a programming problem ?

Comment: @user23463397 "*that sounds like synthetic programming questions are not forbidden *" you're just cherry-picking whatever you think supports your point. The "*a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*" is the relevant part for what is on-topic. Not how somebody feels about code. I write code and I love it (well, some times). Does that mean it's *not* forbidden for me to ask a cooking question? Or is that a complete non-sequitur?

Comment: @VLAZ "'you're just cherry-picking whatever you think supports your point'" -- I could say same of your points

Comment: @user23463397 as a small footnote, please try to avoid txtspk abbreviations like "pls". Abbreviations like that are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @user23463397 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ You've been told what the site is about and where to look for what is or isn't on-topic. We can only warn you not to ask cooking questions because you love writing code. But we can't stop you from doing it.

Comment: Aggression? So people are actually going out of their way to find new joiners in person and beat them up?

Comment: I'm not sure why my tag edits were rolled back. OP is talking about downvotes, closevotes and his closed question...

Comment: @Gimby Nobody went our of their way to find me as a new joiner. I joined this site entirely on my own. Maybe I wouldn't get beat up if someone went out of their way to find me to join

Comment: @Cerbrus I posted this to discuss my experience as a new user. Its not a question about downv-otes specifically.

Comment: Your experience with this question has nothing to do with you being a new user, though. If I had posted that question, I'd have gotten the same treatment. Maybe even harsher, considering I should know better.

Comment: @Cerbrus I would totally believe that if there was no consistency in the level of points earned by all the people who came at me. And now that I have commented this, I wont be surprised if the trend suddenly start to change. With new users coming at me too

Comment: Buddy, _please_ listen to what experienced users are telling you, here. We're trying to help you. It doesn't help if you just stubbornly revert edits.

Comment: When reading links about how to ask a good question and what's on-topic on Stack Overflow it should become clear that the word "problem" is not used as "puzzle" or "challenge", but as "difficulty". Also the question template makes that very clear ("Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen." i.e. you're dealing with something you didn't expect and don't know how to solve it). If you insist that "problem" = "puzzle" you're just playing a semantic game. You had a puzzle, not a problem.

Comment: @yivi this has nothing to do with OP being a new user... He posted a puzzle as a question, he got a _lot_ of feedback, he got ___3___ answers, and then the question got closed.

Comment: @yivi it's completely irrelevant how old OP's account is here. Just because he's new doesn't make this a "new user" discussion. OP is complaining about the closure, about downvotes.

Comment: The answer doesn't dictate the question's tags.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you could read by post again, its not about closure and down votes. I mentioned those as some of the tools that have been used to come at me as a new use. The post is about my experience and how my post was called unclear with experienced users yet they gave no clear reason when I asked them why

Comment: So that last paragraph about abuse of power in downvotes and closevotes isn't a thing then?

Comment: BTW, If you're interesting in programming puzzles in general, including posting some of your own, [there is a site here for that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). PLEASE make sure you read the help pages and note very carefully how the existing questions that are asked, in particular the style and formatting.

Comment: The use of "emphatically" in this post does not make sense, you appear to mean something else.

Comment: @philipxy I suspect they meant "empathetically"

Comment: This is extremely unclear and full of jumps to conclusions. Please read what you wrote. What is it that is supposed to be discussed?

Answer (score 15):

Rather than focus on the post you link to, I'm going to focus on the point you make in your question here. Comments have been made both on the question here, and your "question" on main about why that post isn't on topic.

> On the other hand, specific two people have made comments of clarity, but they were not able to ***emphatically*** say why or what. ... I think this was quite aggressive and unpleasant.

Saying that someone is aggressive is a very *strong* statement. If someone truly was aggressive towards you, then you should be using the flags feature to bring such content to the attention of the mods. For comments there is a little flag icon to the left of the comment you can click; click that and then select "It's unfriendly or unkind." In the post you link, however, I see nothing that would come close to requiring this kind of flag.

Being emphatic to a user is something you shouldn't really expect; Stack Overflow isn't some kind of service or help desk where users will want to feel your frustrations and help you work through your feelings on the matter, as well as the problem. The site is for *specific* programming questions and solutions to those questions. We don't like "noise" in our content, like "Hi", "thanks for your help", "How are you today", etc; posts should get straight to the point and describe the problem in detail, explain the difficulty you (the asker) is having solving that problem, and *ask a question*.

> I was willing to provide all information needed to clarify.

In the post, you don't provide any information on what difficulty *you* are having. As I stated in the comments, the post reads like a homework assignment, not a question. If you attempted to solve the puzzle and failed, and want to *ask* about why your solution failed, great! Don't, however, just post an assignment and expect others to do it (for you); that isn't how the site works.

> I think it's not enough for anyone of higher points to just say a question is not clear.

Contrary to your opinion, this is how the site works. Reputation is seen as a way for users to demonstrate that they understand the site, and so that comes with [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). There are always outliers, where posts are closed incorrectly, or people who don't use their privileges often and so when they do they use them for reasons they weren't intended, but this is a very small percentage.

> The true distinction is the ability to nonaggressively and clearly point out what exactly is wrong

This is what the closure reason is for. It tells you *why* the post was closed, and links to the help centre to an article that covers the likely reasons why your question is closed. There's no aggression there. Users may wish to comment on the why, but unfortunately many don't due to the actions of others; "revenge votes" are a big contribution to why these users don't comment.

> how do we tell a person claiming a question is not clear is doing so out of personal reasons rather than constructive criticisms?

Again, I see nothing personal about the comments made on the post. The comments are about the content, many expressing the problems we have raised here, such as that it isn't a question, and you didn't describe the problem *you* are having solving your "puzzle".

> I think we need a review of the power of downvotes, closure and how people use them. We must make sure it's not abused. I wish to know what or how this community handle such issues.

Well, you're in the right place; Meta is where we discuss such issues. For asking about a question you've posted, ask a well-voiced question with the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag; be prepared to invoke the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

For ideas about votes, this too is the right place, however, this has been discussed *many*, **many, *many*** times, so you *must* do research on those posts beforehand, and bring a new, interesting, well-researched discussion. If you don't do that, your post will most certainly be closed as a duplicate and likely be *very* poorly received.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. For clarity I will respond by points: "Saying that someone is aggressive is a very strong statement. If someone truly was aggressive by threatening you, ......"  First I did not say they someone is aggressive by threatening me. And the definition of aggressive is not only to do with threat. Please lookup a term called "passive-aggression". So I did not make this up or use the word wrongfully as your answer implied

Comment: "For comments there is a little flag icon to the left of the comment you can click; click that and then select "It's unfriendly of unkind." In the post you link, however, I see nothing that would come close to requiring this kind of flag." I hope that you encountered same, then once you know what exactly my experience was, you could be in a better position to judge whether or not your experience require some unkind or unfriendly flag.

Comment: @user23463397 if you meant "passive-aggressive" instead of "aggressive", please fix your question. They're different words.

Comment: Apologies, I misrecalled that flags were accessible to everyone, @user23463397 ; they are actually accessible at *15* reputation.

Comment: One can be aggressive without threats. We can see examples of that all day long in meta. There is plenty to pick on in the question without putting things in the OPs mouth. They never claimed anyone was "threatening" them.

Comment: "Being emphatic to a user is something you shouldn't really expect; Stack Overflow isn't some kind of service or help desk where users will want to feel your frustrations and help you work through your feelings on the matter, as well as the problem."  I think a fundamental principle of criticizing anything is letter the person know why. Otherwise on what basis will the user make the expected change ? Its like saying something is bad but you have refused to share a clear reason why.

Comment: Personally, @yivi,  if someone is aggressive towards me, I find that to be threatening behaviour.

Comment: Your last 3 comments aren't exactly free from passive aggression either, @user23463397: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074409#comment137640271_78074409)/[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfccy.png) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074409/return-elements-from-both-sides-of-item-in-array#comment137648753_78074409)/[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNg4F.png) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074409#comment137648872_78074409)/[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkiTe.png)

Comment: So if someone insults you or belittles you, you would feel "threatened"? Or you mean that you wouldn't find those behaviors "aggressive"? Sorry, not buying it. I think you are playing a "word definition" game. And frankly, it's unnecessary. There is a lot that's right with your answer, and there is plenty that's wrong with the OP's premises. No need to lower to that. Bye.

Comment: "

    I was willing to provide all information needed to clarify.

'In the post, you don't provide any information on what difficulty you are having'. ";  I think @ThomA you may have slightly misunderstood my point on 'willing to provide all information'. e.g user asked a question which I explained (refer to post comments). He then replied in a way I found defensive. Scenario 2, another user (the second one, Ctrlz) said an answer was wrong, yet he refused to say exactly what makes it wrong. Pls check all these in the comments. That's what I meant by "I was willing tp provide all info...."

Comment: *"So if someone insults you or belittles you, you would feel "threatened""* I wouldn't find that aggressive or threathening behaviour, @yivi .

Comment: Emphatically means "forcefully or with emphasis"; Do y'all mean "empathetically", i.e. "in a way that shows you understand how somebody else feels because you can imagine what it would be like to be that person"?

Comment: @ColleenV  Emphatically as in with emphasis is what I meant.  That is they claimed there was something wrong, but they would refuse to point exactly or emphasis on what exactly this problem is. They simply beat about the bush.

Comment: @user23463397 In that case, you are probably looking for ["explicitly"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explicitly) or *in an explicit manner : clearly and without any vagueness or ambiguity* I feel like this answer misinterpreted your usage though.